Deserialize Azure Communication Services Delivery Report missing DeliveryAttemptTimestamp property
When I attempt to deserialize the payload of a AcsEmailDeliveryReportReceivedEventData I have received via an Azure Service Bus queue, the object is hydrated correctly except for the DeliveryAttemptTimestamp property.
I have tried both of the following methods as well as a couple of variations on each.
var deliveryReport = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<AcsEmailDeliveryReportReceivedEventData>(eventGridEvent!.Data);

and
if (eventGridEvent.Data is BinaryData binaryData)
{
    var eventData = binaryData.ToObjectFromJson<AcsEmailDeliveryReportReceivedEventData>();
}

In both scenarios the DeliveryAttemptTimestamp property is null, but debugging and looking at the raw data, I know it has a value set.
Additional method now tried and exact same result. Becoming increasingly convinced this is a bug in the Nuget package.
bool success = eventGridEvent.TryGetSystemEventData(out object eventData1);

Example payload is:
{
  "sender": "sender@example.com",
  "recipient": "receiver@example.com",
  "messageId": "b65c4713-17b4-434d-932b-ec75c9af20a8",
  "status": "Delivered",
  "deliveryStatusDetails": {
    "statusMessage": ""
  },
  "deliveryAttemptTimestamp": "2024-06-04T00:13:45.905\u002B00:00"
}

It is possible that it is a bug, I found the following Githug Issue which was related to another issue with this property, so the encoding of the + with \u002B could be messing up the deserialization.
Anyone know of the correct way to deserialize this object?

can you try  with var options = new JsonSerializerOptions {     PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true // Handle case-insensitive property names }; var deliveryReport = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<AcsEmailDeliveryReportReceivedEventData>(json, options);

have you tried above code?

I have created an issue https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/44379 for the library team, as this definitely appears to be a bug. As stated in the issue, it is only the one property that is not hydrated correctly.

To deserialize the payload of an AcsEmailDeliveryReportReceivedEventData, including the DeliveryAttemptTimestamp property, we need to configure case-insensitive properties.
The code below deserializes the JSON payload into the AcsEmailDeliveryReportReceivedEventData object, including the DeliveryAttemptTimestamp property.
public class AcsEmailDeliveryReportReceivedEventData
{
    public string Sender { get; set; }
    public string Recipient { get; set; }
    public string MessageId { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public DeliveryStatusDetails DeliveryStatusDetails { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset DeliveryAttemptTimestamp { get; set; }
}

public class DeliveryStatusDetails
{
    public string StatusMessage { get; set; }
}

var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true // Handle case-insensitive property names
};
var deliveryReport = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<AcsEmailDeliveryReportReceivedEventData>(json, options);


